# Restoring an SQL Server 2012 MDF to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore SQL Server 2012 backup to a SQL Server 2008 database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20588/restore-sql-server-2012-backup-to-a-sql-server-2008-database)

I have created a database on SQL server 2012 with compatibility mode for SQL server 2008 (100).
When I do a backup and try to restore it on an SQL 2008 I get an error. Same goes for attach/detach.

Is there a way to move/restore/migrate it to SQL Server 2008?

Thanks

Tomer

Answer (score 4):

Your only avenue is to export the database and then import it back on SQL 2008. SSMS has an [Export/Import Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) you can give a shot. Other tools exists from 3rd party vendors like Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to copy the schema and [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to copy the data. I'm sure there are more. The gist of it that you need to go through some sort of export/import, SQL Server does not support any downgrade path for the MDF format. Obviously, you must not had rely on new SQL Server 2012 features like [columnstores](http://rusanu.com/2012/05/29/inside-the-sql-server-2012-columnstore-indexes/).