# get data from express edition db to developer edition

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms, sql-server-2017

How to get database in new created SSMS sql server developer edition but I don't have back up of database but mdf file and ldf file are available.

Comment: How do you have the same data on the C drive?  Do you mean you have the mdf and ldf files that did not get deleted when you uninstalled developer edition?

Comment: yes ldf and mdf files are still there I've uninstalled express edition and installed developer edition

Comment: So re-install express edition, [attach the database files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) take your back up and move forward.  You could try attaching the files to developer edition, but they may not work.

Comment: ok but how could can I get back data again

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thank you for your answer but I solved It out by using this link https://support.resellerclub.com/helpdesk/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/260/5/steps-to-attach-mdf-and-ldf-files-of-mssql-databases-to-convert-it-to-bak-format

Answer (score 2):

If you have the mdf file, you have your data.  Re-install the SQL express edition, [attach the database file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) take a backup and restore it to your developer edition, see [Restore database according to editions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174207/21924) if you have issues with the restore.

If you don't have the mdf file and you don't have a backup, it is gone, start over.

When you installed developer edition, if you created a database with the same name, and put the mdf and ldf files in the same place as the old SQL express edition, then you overwrote the mdf files and your data is gone.